# Android App reverse engineering

Tags: android

I am working on Android app mobile application security project. While performing security testing i successfully reverse engineer android app using dex2jar utility. I got access for source code. My question is after reverse engineer the code which is getting is it a real source code write by a developer or any compiled code. Also is this vulnerability is applicable to each android app or there is any mitigation to avoid this vulnerability. And if this vulnerability is applicable to each android app then how severe is this vulnerability.

Comment: the phone has to be able to run the code right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fairly unavoidable and for the most part isn't a problem. If you try this for any android app you'll be able to get source code using the Dex2Jar tool.

The best you can do is use [ProGuard](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html) to obfuscate your source code. This makes the source harder (but not impossible) to read.